Moment JS isBetween Not Working as Expected on Date Objects
I have a Date object and I want to check if it's tomorrow.
const dateToCheck: Date //Sat Jun 01 2024 09:00:00 GMT-0700

I calculated tomorrow like this:
const tomorrow = moment().add(1, 'day')

The start and end of tomorrow are found like this:
tomorrow.startOf('day') //Sat Jun 01 2024 00:00:00 GMT-0700
tomorrow.endOf('day') //Sat Jun 01 2024 23:59:59 GMT-0700

When I try to determine if the date I'm checking is tomorrow, it's false:
var isTomorrow = moment(dateToCheck).isBetween(
  tomorrow.startOf('day'),
  tomorrow.endOf('day'),
)
console.log(isTomorrow) //false

As far as I can tell, isTomorrow should be true because Sat Jun 01 2024 09:00:00 is between Sat Jun 01 2024 00:00:00 and Sat Jun 01 2024 23:59:59.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

startOf and endOf modify the original Moment object. When you call isBetween(tomorrow.startOf('day'), tomorrow.endOf('day')) the isBetween function receives the same object for the start and end dates.
You need to make copies of the tomorrow object when calling the function:
const isTomorrow = moment(dateToCheck).isBetween(
  moment(tomorrow).startOf('day'),
  moment(tomorrow).endOf('day')
)
console.log(isTomorrow) // true


Ah, brilliant! I would have never figured that out on my own.  Thank you!

For more accuracy I'd convert them to ECMAScript epoch and then treat them as integers...
var D1='Sat Jun 01 2024 23:59:59';

var D2='Sat Jun 01 2024 00:00:00';


D1=new Date(D1).getTime()/1000;

D2=new Date(D2).getTime()/1000;


if(D1-D2 < 86400){

 // same day

} else {

 // next day

}

Or something like that.

Why do you think this will be more accurate? What do you think moment.js is doing internally?

Can you show how you set D1 and D2 dynamically to tomorrow's date, rather than hard-coding it?

Numbers are always easier to play with and make more sense visually.

High-level abstractions are also easy to work with.

That’s relative… as long as you remember what they actually do.

Plus it removes a large, no longer recommended library!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
